How can I get live telemetry data from DJI Fly/ DJI Pilot
I need to receive live telemetry data (once every 1 -2 seconds) from DJI Fly or DJI Pilot, while on RC Plus
Note that making my own MSDK app to connect to the drone for this is not an option. However, an APP that can run on background and read the data and send to a server is welcome.
What can be done? Thank you
